# loop through array and save x observations in new array

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

I am trying to loop through array and for `i`. I need to MAX values of previous 10 values.

So `if i= 20`, I need to `math.max i-10, i-9, i-8...` and so forth. But I am struggling to get this to work.

```
static public void TA(DateTime[] datePrice, double[] openPrice, double[] highPrice, double[] lowPrice, double[] closePrice)
{
    #region declare variables
    int outBegIdx;
    int outNbElement;
    int SmaPeriod = 20;
    int TOTAL_PERIODS = closePrice.Length;
    double[] outputSma = new double[closePrice.Length];
    double[] outputStdDev = new double[closePrice.Length];
    int[] outputShootingStar = new int[closePrice.Length];
    int[] outputHangingMan = new int[closePrice.Length];
    int[] outputEngulf = new int[closePrice.Length];
    int[] outputMaxIndex = new int[closePrice.Length];
    double[] outputTrueRange = new double[closePrice.Length];
    double accProfit = 0;
    int position = 0;
    double openPosPrice = 0;
    double profit = 0;
    #endregion

    #region not sure what this code is for
    //for (int i = 0; i < closePrice.Length-TOTAL_PERIODS; i++) //had to change from -1 to -TOTAL_PERIODS
    //{
    //    openPrice[i] = (double)i;
    //    highPrice[i] = (double)i;
    //    lowPrice[i] = (double)i;
    //    closePrice[i] = (double)i;
    //}
    #endregion

    #region Technical Libary
    TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode Sma = Core.Sma(0, closePrice.Length - 1, closePrice, SmaPeriod, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement, outputSma);
    TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode StdDev = Core.StdDev(0, closePrice.Length - 1, closePrice, closePrice.Length, 1, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement, outputStdDev);
    TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode ShootingStar = Core.CdlShootingStar(0, closePrice.Length - 1, openPrice, highPrice, lowPrice, closePrice, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement, outputShootingStar);
    TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode HangingMan = Core.CdlHangingMan(0, closePrice.Length - 1, openPrice, highPrice, lowPrice, closePrice, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement, outputHangingMan);
    TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode BullIngulf = Core.CdlEngulfing(0, closePrice.Length - 1, openPrice, highPrice, lowPrice, closePrice, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement, outputEngulf);
    TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode TrueRange = Core.TrueRange(0, closePrice.Length - 1, highPrice, lowPrice, closePrice, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement, outputTrueRange);
    //TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode xx = Core.bu
    //TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode MaxIndex = Core.MaxIndex(0, closePrice.Length - 1, highPrice, 20, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement, outputMaxIndex);
    #endregion

    for (int i = 20; i < closePrice.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j--)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code that you have written so far

Comment: Your existing codes would help us to understand your errors :)

Comment: So you need the n greatest values? or what?

Comment: you want maximum of ten previous elements? what should be the  output for first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another version in LINQ

```
var list = new List<int>();
var max = list.Select((x, i) => //get items (x as value, i as index
                  list.Skip(Math.Max(i - 10, 0)) //forget about previous items
                    .Take(Math.Min(10, i + 1)) // get 10(or less) elements before this element 
                    .Max()) // get maximum of them
              .ToList();//convert result to list
```

and a test would be like this

```
var l = new List<int>
{
    1, 4, 3, 8, 2, 11, 4, 3, 5, 19, 2, 8,
    11, 13, 14, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12
};
var max = l.Select((x, i) => l.Skip(Math.Max(i - 10, 0)).Take(Math.Min(10, i + 1)).Max()).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", max));
//1,4,4,8,8,11,11,11,11,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,14,14,14
```

Comment: Thanks @dotctor this was what i was looking for. I got it to work as intended. Really appreciate the help. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code :

```
int[] arr = new int[200];                // Original list of lines
List<int> maxList = new List<int>();     // Result list to hold max values
int[] range = new int[10];               // Sub-list of lines to check max value
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 9; i++)
{
    Array.Copy(arr, i, range, 0, 10);    // Get sub-set of lines
    maxList.Add(range.Max());            // Find max, add it to the result list
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement it @user3021830, it does not work as intended (therefore i will try to explain the requirement in greater detail). lets say i have 200 line of data. I start on line 20 and loop to 200. When starting at line 20, i need to look at the previous line and find the max value, which i need to store. Then i move to line 21, and here i find the max of the previous 10 lines... and so forth. So its more like a "moving 10 day max"

Comment: This code also does the same I guess. Starting from 10 and going back to last 10 elements also means starting from 1 and going forward to 10 elements. The logic is to create a subset, find the max of the subset, save it. then slide the subset index by +1 and do it again until all elements are scanned. Did I get it right?

Comment: Okay i guess. But actually i need to save 1 value for each line - even though its the same value. as i need to use it like this... if value[i] > max[i] .... so how would you do that?

Comment: for (int i = 20; i < closePrice.Length-1; i++)
                {
                    Array.Copy(closePrice, i, range, 0, closePrice.Length-21);
                    maxList.Add(range.Max());

Comment: i tried to do it like this. but i am getting "source array not long enough"

Comment: The List<int> maxList holds the single value of each line. 

maxList[0] holds the max of lines (1 - 10), maxList[1] holds the max of lines (2-11), maxList[2] holds the max of lines (3-12) and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension method like this one:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftSegAggregate<TItem, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TItem> items, 
    Func<IEnumerable<TItem>, TResult> aggregator, 
    int segmentLength)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (segmentLength <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("segmentLength");

    int i = 0, c = 0;
    var segment = new TItem[segmentLength];
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        c++;
        segment[i++ % segmentLength] = item;         
        yield return aggregator(segment.Take(c));
    }
}
```

This method create array for store current segment.
For each item in target collection aggregator function applied to segment array and return next result (max of this segment for example).

- **No memory reallocation, no copying**, just simple array that filled cyclically;
- You can use collection of any type - just provide aggregation function;
- You can get as many enumerators as you want and use them in your loop;

Example:

```
// Sample items (some complex objects for example).
var items = new[] { 1, -3, 6, 5, -2, 0, 3, 4, 8, 0, 4, 7, 2, 9, -3 }
    .Select(
        i => new {
            Name = string.Format("Item {0}", i), 
            Value = i                        
        }
    ).ToArray();

// Get enumerator of segment max for Value field.
var segMaxEnumerator = items.LeftSegAggregate(
    // Aggregation function (returns max value from segment of items).
    seg => seg.Select(i => i.Value).Max(),
    // Size of target segment.
    10  
).GetEnumerator();

// Here is your loop:
for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{                
    // Move segment max enumerator to next item.
    segMaxEnumerator.MoveNext();

    // Use segMaxEnumerator.Current to take segment max.
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, segMaxEnumerator.Current);
}
```